# What is the preferred way to filter a regex search for duplicate matches in C#

Tags: c#, regex, duplicates

A new question has arisen in relation to an [earlier question of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3433774/c-regex-on-a-streamreader-will-not-return-matches). I have some code that is using a regex to find email addresses. It's working great except that it returns duplicate matches. I searched this site and found a question from a long time ago that was dealing with a similar problem, and the answer had something to do with mixing the regex logic with a string[] and the Distinct() method. Unfortunately my understanding of arrays is still limited.

My code is placing all the regex matches into a `MatchCollection`. Aside from that, how do I go about interacting with this `MatchCollection` to only add unique matches to the regex?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can do it using [**`Distinct`**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb348436.aspx) in .NET 3.5 or newer if you call [**`Cast`**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb341406.aspx) on your match collection so that you can use the LINQ extension methods:

```
MatchCollection matchCollection = Regex.Matches(input, pattern);
List<string> matches = matchCollection
    .Cast<Match>()
    .Select(m => m.Value)
    .Distinct()
    .ToList();
```

This assumes that you have the following usings at the top of your file:

```
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;
```